# Не отображается загруженный index.html

Tags: загрузка

Создана страница в ворде, сохранена как веб страница. Загружаю на сервер хостинга все файлы, которые были созданы при сохранении, т.е. index.hmt и все файлы из папки index.files

После загрузки всего содержимого, обновляю страницы ресурса в браузере и вижу просто пустую белую страницу.В чем может быть проблема, что проверить?

Comment: www.trees-store.ru Спасибо :)

Comment: `index.hmt` ? может `index.html` или  `index.htm` ?

Comment: htm описАлась :)

Comment: упс..сейчас проверю

Comment: расширение файлов правильное? в вопросе `index.hmt` ? что это такое за расширение?

Comment: Нет. Виден в числе загруженных

Comment: Возмжно вы файлы загружаете не в ту папку, на хостингах обычно надо грузить в publlic_html или что-то вроде того

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fhiDnKk.png

Comment: @Наталья [view-source:http://trees-store.ru/](view-source:http://trees-store.ru/) пробегите по ссылкам - почти все ссылки ведут на 404

Comment: файлы гружу сюда: https://www.nic.ru/hcp/cgi-bin/gen_avd.pl?mItem=web_server&hitem=fm&page=dir&path=home/trees/trees-store.ru/docs/&action=open  Так рекомендовали в Ru CENRE

Comment: Alex, и что это значит?

Comment: Так и есть вроде. Только не папка index.files, а файлы, которые в ней сохранились при сохранении из ворд

Comment: Алекс, а в чем может быть ошибка при загрузке?

Comment: Веб-сервер/Файловый менеджер/home/treestrees-store.ru/docs это путь загрузки

Comment: @Наталья [пример](http://testwork.ru/stackoverflow/TEST%20TEST%20TEST.htm) корректно загруженного файла

Comment: Далее был удален файл который лежал по умолчанию, вместо него загружены те файлы, которые сохранились при сохранении веб документа из ворда. Только грузились они по отдельности, в т.ч. из папки index.files

Comment: Да, Алекс, я это понимаю

Comment: Секрета нет, но хочу сама разобраться. Я не же не могу каждый раз потом вам все высылать :) Попробовала перезагрузить - тот же результат :(

Comment: что-то мне кажется, что вам в index.html надо подправить пути. А то если открыть `http://trees-store.ru/index.files/filelist.xml` то будет 404 а если `http://trees-store.ru/filelist.xml` то файл найден. так же и с другими xml. По поводу картинки. Тоже путь скорее всего не `index.files/image009.png`,  а просто `image009.png`. ... Как я понял, у вас на компе папка index.files есть, а при заливке на хост вы копируете напрямую, уже без папки.

Comment: Да с путем Вы правы, потому что файл 009 лежит не в папке, а сразу в корне docs,  а вот что можно поправить в index.htm если его сам ворд создал?

Comment: потому что картинка вот `http://trees-store.ru/image009.png` =)) ну что что. просто в файле index.html удаляем слова `index.files/` .Например будет не `<link rel=File-List href="index.files/filelist.xml">`, а `<link rel=File-List href="filelist.xml">`... Правда `editdata.mso` я у вас так и не нашел. он все равно 404 при любом раскладе

Comment: Да) Уже сама поняла. Логично. Сейчас попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: YES!!! Только почему все так размазано и нечетко? :( www.trees-store.ru

Comment: И ссылки мертвые.... Возможно ли в ворде сделать что-то лучше, или это предел?

Comment: Попробуйте, кстати, залить непосредственно сразу папку index.files с содержимым. Глядишь тогда и править пути не надо будет и возможно заработает. А вообще в ворде давно никто ничего не делает.

Comment: Все залилось. Поправила путь, Как Вы и сказали. Конечно не делают. Но я ж чайник, а они могут) Но буду признательна, если подскажите как можно такое сделать просто и с живыми ссылками.http://www.trees-store.ru/

Comment: @Наталья для верстки не через word почитайте про [html](http://htmlbook.ru/html5) и [css3](http://htmlbook.ru/css3)

Answer (score 1):

Итак. Поэтапно.

1) Вы что-то делаете в word-e. Сохраняете это так:

`Сохранить как -> веб страница`.

Допустим имя будет `project`.

2) Word вам создаст файл `project.htm` и папку `project.files` в директории, в которой вы указали.

3) Вы  **и** файл `project.htm` **и папку** `project.files` копируете на хост.

4) Чтобы хост знал, что отсчет надо вести именно с файла `project.htm` вам еще нужен дополнительный файлик `.htaccess`

Его можно:

- создать в блокноте и сохранить как `.htaccess`. Важно (!!!) никакного имени ему присваивать не надо! Просто точка htaccess
- или скачайте его тут к примеру https://yadi.sk/d/TkzcC52RjsewF

5) Открываем файл `.htaccess` с помощью блокнота и добавляем в него строку:

`DirectoryIndex project.htm`

Сохраняем

6) Кидаем файл `.htaccess` на хост к остальным файлам так, чтобы `.htaccess` и файл `project.htm` были в одной директории

**(!)** Всегда нужен будет вам .htaccess. Если будете сохранять проект по-другому, то придется в .htaccess писать именно это имя файла, под которым сохранен проект

**Итог:**
папка на хостинге выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

внутри файла .htaccess выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Наталья у  элемента `span`, который вокруг картинки `image008.png`   написан `z-index:251658240`. найдите его и сделайте `z-index: -1`  тогда ссылки будут поверх картинки и будут кликаться